Why doesn't TypeScript recognize the if/else logic for a prop that is restricted to 3 strings?
I have React + TypeScript code like this:
type Props = {
  type: 'exams' | 'exam attempt' | 'review questions';
};

export default function Header({ type }: Props) {
  let text: string;

  if (type === 'exams' || type === 'exam attempt') }
    text = "Exams";
  } else if (type === 'review questions') {
    text = "Review Questions"
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {text}
    </div>
  );
}

TypeScript complains with this error: Variable 'text' is used before being assigned.
But I thought TypeScript understands if/else logic. In this code, type is always going to be assigned to a string.
Why doesn't TypeScript understand the if/else logic?

Typescript isn't smart enough to know that your if / else if is exhaustive of all possible string conditions. I'm not sure why myself. If you change else if to else and remove the condition then Typescript detects exhaustive assignment.

See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56527 and the other q/a linked above
